# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ELAttributeEvaluator

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tiles

***Error Occur at the time of start server***

```
  SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/el/ELAttributeEvaluator
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.createELEvaluator(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:247)
        at org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesContainerFactory.createAttributeEvaluatorFactory(StrutsTilesContainerFactory.java:198)
        at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:106)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
        at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
        at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.el.ELAttributeEvaluator
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
        ... 15 more

    Nov 08, 2016 4:10:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    Nov 08, 2016 4:10:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/TilesStrutDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
    Nov 08, 2016 4:10:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Nov 08, 2016 4:10:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Nov 08, 2016 4:10:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 3332 ms
```

***web.xml of the project***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>TilesStrutDemo</display-name>
       <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
       </welcome-file-list>
      <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <filter-class>
             org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
          </filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

***struts.xml of this project***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="login" class="com.action.login.LoginDemo">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/welcome.tiles</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="customer" class="com.action.login.LoginDemo">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">/customer.success.tiles</result>
        </action> 
    </package>
</struts>
```

***tiles.xml configuration ***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Welcome.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="/customer.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Customer Form" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Customer.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="/customer.success.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Customer Added" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/SuccessCustomer.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

***Menu.jsp***

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Menu.....
</body>
</html>
```

**Header.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Header..........
</body>
</html>
```

***BaseLayout.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
    <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="250"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
            <td width="350"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Footer.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Footer.............
</body>
</html>
```

***insert.jsp***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login">
    <s:textarea name="number" label="number"/>
    <s:submit value="Click" name="Click"></s:submit>
</s:form>
<s:url action="customer">Customer</s:url>
</body>
</html>
```

***loginDemo.java for action which call by action ***

```
package com.action.login;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginDemo extends ActionSupport{
    private int num;

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
    public String login(){
        if(num%2==0){
            return SUCCESS;
        }else{
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
    public String customer(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

***lib add jar***

```
    commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
    commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
    commons-digester-2.0.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar
    commons-io-2.2.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
    freemarker-2.3.22.jar
    ognl-3.0.19.jar
    struts2-core-2.3.31.jar
    struts2-tiles-plugin-2.3.31.jar
    tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
    tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
    tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
    xwork-core-2.3.31.jar
    tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
    slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
    tiles-compat-3.0.1.jar
    tiles-ognl-2.2.2.jar
    tiles-freemarker-2.2.2.jar
    javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
    struts2-tiles3-plugin-2.3.31.jar


    JDK1.8
    Tomcat 1.8
```

Comment: You are missing `tiles-el-2.2.2.jar`, the missing class is in that file.